# How to manipulate JSON objects sent by $.ajax in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Alright , so i've been trying to find an answer to this question for quite a while now and every single solution doesn't seem to work for me for some reason I'm still not sure about . So here is my $.ajax code

```
PostData.push({
        "PostRequestType" : "updateBasicInformation",
        "newDisplayNameUser" : FormData[0].value,
        "newUserNameUser" : FormData[1].value,
        "newEmailUser" : FormData[2].value,
        "newSearchRadius" : FormData[3].value,
        "newIsAnonymous" : FormData[4].value
    });

    PostData = JSON.stringify(PostData);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./updateUserSettings.php",
        data: {"BasicInformationData" : PostData},
        success: function(result)
        {
            $("#ErrorSection").append(result);

            if(result == "success")
            {
                $("#Form1Status").addClass('success');
                $("#Form1Status").append("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#Form2Status").addClass('failure');
                $("#Form2Status").append("Erreur SQL");
            }
        }

    });
```

and here is this simple PHP code I'm trying to execute

```
$jsonOBJ = json_decode($_POST['BasicInformationData']);

echo $jsonOBJ->newDisplayNameUser;
```

Multiple threads seem to suggest this is the correct way to do this but for some reason it doesn't seem to yield any result and I've tried multiple variations of this code , I tried to use $jsonOBJ[X] or other combinations like these but nothing seems to have worked so far .

So I am asking , how do I properly utilize a json object within PHP ?

Comment: Id dump this key `BasicInformationData` and just send the serialized data.  By having that key in there you are sending the JSON data as a string.

Comment: what is the form of your parameter in your server side?

Comment: For the beginning, it is a sane idea to do `var_dump($_POST)`. This might narrow down a problem. Another thing, if `echo $jsonOBJ->newDisplayNameUser` doesn't throw you an error, than JSON decoded fine. In such case, the reason nothing echoed might be that `$jsonOBJ->newDisplayNameUser` has empty value. Try to do `var_dump($jsonOBJ->newDisplayNameUser)`, it will give you more info than `echo`.